# How can I write an if thats related to a single else, then beneath it an if that is related to a different else?

Tags: c

I want to relate each if statement to the else one below it only. So when the if isn't true the else beneath it is active alone. Then the next if will be run, and the else below that one will be used if its FALSE. How can I do this?

```
if (.....){
}
else (....){
}
if (.....){
}
else (....){
}
if (.....){
}
else (....){
}
```

Comment: Does this structure not give the behavior you want? If not, this would be clearer if you made an actual tiny program with just enough variables and prints to show a difference between what you want/expect and what you get. (That is, an easy [mre].)

Comment: It does seem that what you've described is exactly what that code would do.

Comment: You have it sort of right, except there's no condition `(....)` after else, just start the opening bracket right away.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ternary` operator in `C`.
The syntax is as follows

```c
result = binaryCondition ? valueReturnedIfTrue : valueReturnedIfFalse;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way of solving this would be to simply exit once you've have entered any `if...else` block. You can do this with either a `return` statement inside each conditional, or a `break`. As long as all of your conditionals are within a loop or outer block, this will bypass your other `if...else` statements.

For example:

```
if (a) {
 return b + 1
} else {
 return b + 2
}
```

or:

```
if (a) {
 b += 1
break
} else {
 b += 2
break
}
```